# File Extraction from BI Tool

Tags: automated-testing, manual-testing, jmeter, load-testing

I have the task to validate the file extraction from the BI tool to ensure the records are extracting as we expected from the Report.

My Question is

During file Extraction We using the option as CSV to download the file.While downloading application taking bit time to process records from DB using queries

Is any way to check the speed & Performance of the file extraction

I need to check how much time it taking process to complete the action

Let me know your thoughts and feedback.

Answer (score 1):

Use resource monitor which comes with windows.
You can monitor ram,HDD read write speed and network usage for a given processor.

Comment: I will try it out

Answer (score 1):

You can simulate simultaneous file downloads by multiple users using JMeter's [HTTP Request](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Request) sampler.

If you need to store downloaded files for later analysis you can use [Save Responses to a file](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Save_Responses_to_a_file) listener

Check out [Performance Testing: Upload and Download Scenarios with Apache JMeter](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-performance-test-upload-and-download-scenarios-apache-jmeter) article for more information on how to properly configure JMeter to mimic file upload and download operations.